# Swagger Swashbuckle not showing response object in swagger.json

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

swagger 2.0.

.netcore 2.1

swashbuckle as in the image.

[image]

I have this attribute on an api endpoint:

```
[SwaggerResponse(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(List<Cat>), description: "successful operation")]
```

When I run the API and navigate to https://localhost:44394/swagger/v1/swagger.json the json is there but  the `SwaggerResponse` seems to be being ignored.

This is an example of what I receive:

```
"/api/data/cats": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "CatApi"
    ],
    "operationId": "GetCatsById",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "catIds",
        "in": "query",
        "required": true,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        },
        "collectionFormat": "multi",
        "uniqueItems": false
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

You can see that the response just show a 200 and I'm not exactly sure where it's getting that description from - as you can see in the attribute it should be `successful operation` and my XML comment is `<response code="200">successful operation</response>`.

I'm very confused. How can I get Swashbuckle it use the `SwaggerResponse` attribute when it generates the json?

More info:
If I use `[ProducesResponseType(statusCode: 200, type: typeof(List<Cat>))]` then I get what I want:

```
"/api/data/cats": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "CatsApi"
    ],
    "operationId": "GetCatsById",
    "consumes": [],
    "produces": [
      "text/plain",
      "application/json",
      "text/json"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "catIds",
        "in": "query",
        "required": true,
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "integer",
          "format": "int32"
        },
        "collectionFormat": "multi",
        "uniqueItems": false
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "Success",
        "schema": {
          "uniqueItems": false,
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Cat"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
```

You can see the additional data in the `produces` field and the `schema` in the `responses` field.

I could change to use `ProducesResponseType` everywhere but it isn't a standard field as far as Swagger is concerned - if I ever regenerate the code from the swagger file then I'll have to always make these changes so I'd like to get it working with `SwaggerResponse`.

Comment: That should have worked.... the project even has unit tests for it: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/8f85d3e663caeda076d81adfde5e5ad90102d1fd/test/WebSites/Basic/Controllers/SwaggerAnnotationsController.cs#L12

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code

Comment: Yes all my Googling suggests it should work so maybe it's something to do with my set up... I've ended up using `ProducesResponseType` as I didn't have enough time. If I get some time I'll set up a basic project to test it again.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Double check if your are *missing the Swagger Decorator Attributes*, follow this below and replace the attributes with your specific `Types` / `MyModel`

---

Since you didn't put up your actual code, *to see how it works, use the default samples for e.g*. you can Install my Swashbuckle.Examples NuGet package. Decorate your methods with the new SwaggerResponseExample attributes below and you will see it work just fine!

```
// These attributes will help with your nested objects
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type=typeof(IEnumerable<Country>))]
[SwaggerResponseExample(HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(CountryExamples))]
[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<ErrorResource>))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string lang)
```

---

Ste 2: Also **ensure you have it configured like so**

```
configuration
    .EnableSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
    })
    .EnableSwaggerUi();
```

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you have the right using for the annotations. I searched and searched because the `SwaggerResponse` were missing and i couldn't get my head behind it.

I somehow managed to use Nswag Annotations, but needed Swashbucke using:

```
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations;
```

I think it came because as i didn't have a nuget for `SwaggerResponse` installed and the first suggestion for a nuget package that has this type was nswag.

Comment: and also enable annotation:  
`services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});`